# Finding the closed form of a real valued power series

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

First of all the task was to find the radius of convergence $\rho$ of:

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \left ( \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2k}\right)(2x-4)^{2k}$$

I am pretty sure $\rho=\frac{1}{2}$ is correct.

Now we had to look for the derivative of the power series which I think should be:

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}2^{2k}(x-2)^{2k-1}$$

And finally we should find the closed form of:

$$f:(2-\rho,2+\rho) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}:x \mapsto \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}2^{2k}(x-2)^{2k-1}$$

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k2^{2k+2}(x-2)^{2k+1}=4(x-2)\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k2^{2k}(x-2)^{2k}=4(x-2)\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \left ( -4(x-2)^2 \right )^k$

$$=4(x-2)\left( \frac{1}{1+4(x-2)^2} \right ) = \frac{4(x-2)}{1+4(x-2)^2}$$

This should be justified, since $x \in (1.5,2.5)$

Is this correct? Would be great if someone could look over it :)

Comment: @CoffeeArabica The $k$ in the denominator of the second line... is that an error?

Comment: No, its the anti derivative of what I actually wanted to get the closed form of. 2k in the denominator dissapeared when I derived the function

Comment: But what is your original problem? With or without the $k$ in the denominator?

Comment: Actually I had to find it for both, but I wanted to firstly get the closed form of the derivative which is without the k. And than take the antiderivative so i habe both of them.

Comment: I fixxed the weird part i guess? ;) srry

Comment: Looks fine. But if you want a closed form for the first series, then you need to integrate what you found at the end. You should get $\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+4(x-2)^2)$.

Comment: Yes it worked as you can see in my answer :)) thank you

Answer (score 1):

Now the sum of the antiderivative of the series I found the closef form already:

$$\int \frac{4(x-2)}{4(x-2)^2+1}dx$$

$u=x-2 \Longrightarrow dx=du$

Substituting:

$$\int \frac{4u}{4u^2+1}du$$

$v=4u^2+1 \Longrightarrow du=\frac{dv}{8u}$

Substituting:

$$\int \frac{4u}{v}\frac{1}{8u}dv=\int \frac{1}{2v}dv=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{v}dv=\frac{1}{2}\left [ \ln(|v|) \right ]$$

Resubstituting:

$$\frac{1}{2}\left [ \ln(|4u^2+1|) \right ]$$

Resubstituting:

$$\frac{1}{2}\left [ \ln(|4(x-2)^2+1|) \right ]=\frac{1}{2}\left [ \ln(4(x-2)^2+1) \right ]=\int\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k+1}2^{2k}(x-2)^{2k-1}dx=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}2^{2k}}{2k}(x-2)^{2k}$$

So yes as @jijijojo promised me the closed form of the second series was $\frac{1}{2}\left [ \ln(4(x-2)^2+1) \right ]$ :)